# Revert the changes made to the master branch git

Tags: github

I didn't know i was working on the master branch and pushed all my changes into the master. Is there way i can pull all the changes from the master to the development and revert the changes made to the master to the original state ?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should save your existing work by putting it in a separate branch

```
git checkout -b temporary
```

Then go back to master and remove the commits, you can change HEAD~[x] where x is the number of commits you want to go back.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push origin master -f
```

Comment: This advice is dangerous if you work with other people! 

You should use git revert or you will have problems with code on branches that were created off of the previous state.